# Vertical rhythm and margin adjust in compass

Tags: html, css, sass, compass-sass

Im trying to understand why I need to increase the value in pixel to reduce margin. Let me add some code.

First the basic:

```
$base-font-size: 16px; 
$base-line-height: 24px;
@include establish-baseline;
```

The I want to reduce some margin in a tag, to do that I increase the value in pixel:

```
 h3 {
  font-weight:500;
  @include adjust-font-size-to(26px); 
  margin: rhythm(1, 56px) 0 0 0; /* 2 line above, 1 line below */
}
```

Why I need to increase the px value?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think your question is a bit unclear.

First of all, what do you mean with "increase the value in pixel", which value ?

Also, its very incomplete, are you using some resets or blueprint ?

```
$base-font-size: 16px; 
$base-line-height: 24px;
@include establish-baseline;
```

So, with this you set up your baseline, thats ok.

```
h3 {
 font-weight:500;
 @include adjust-font-size-to(26px); 
 margin: rhythm(1, 56px) 0 0 0; /* 2 line above, 1 line below */
```

}

But this part is unclear. If you are not using nothing more than the code you wrote, there are no margin or padding applied, so you question is invalid.

You have to specify where this values comes. Also I think you should have a look to reference:

http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/typography/vertical_rhythm/

Also, this can help:

https://medium.com/typography/34fe2f1d2c02

Please, update the answer and add extra info.

Comment: Actually few weeks ago I found my mistake, What I want to do is to change the line-height in some html elements like some h2 in columns etc. So this simple code work fine:    
     @include adjust-font-size-to(36px); 
     line-height:rhythm(0.7) ;line-height:rhythm(0.7) ;

Comment: Ok, great. I think you should edit your answer or accept mine ;-)

Best !